# No builtin modules when calling b2 on a file with -f

Tags: built-in, bjam, boost-build, b2, jam

Given the file `test.jam`:

```
import path ;
```

Running it with `b2 -f test.jam` gives:

```
test.jam:1: in module scope
ERROR: rule "import" unknown in root module.
```

even though `path` is one of the [builtin modules](https://www.bfgroup.xyz/b2/manual/main/index.html#bbv2.reference.modules).

How can I import builtin modules when calling b2 with `-f` ?

`b2 --help-options` says (extract):

```
-fx; Read 'x' as the Jamfile for building instead of searching for the B2 system.
```

I know that `-f` is not the standard way to call b2, but I want to write a tool that fetches b2 variables values and would like to avoid having to create a specific file tree for that (the tool should be able to run in a directory that already has a `jamfile`).

Comment: Note: config flags such as `--config`, `--debug-config` could help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `-f` does not [bootstrap](https://www.bfgroup.xyz/b2/manual/main/#bbv2.reference.init) and that you have to explicitely bootstrap.

Change `test.jam` to:

```
# Manually bootstrap to get access to builtin modules
# apparently this is needed to use this file with `b2 -f <file>`
.bootstrap-file = "$(BOOST_ROOT)/tools/build/src/bootstrap.jam" ;
include "$(.bootstrap-file)" ;

import path ;
```